# Middleware vs SOA

Tags: soa, middleware

Is SOA is part of Middleware or is it the other way around? Im quite confused as how to differentiate both of them. Definition wise, Middleware is computer software that provides services to software applications beyond those available from the operating system. While service oriented architecture is an architectural pattern where in services are provided to the other components. Any simple example are very much appreciated. Tqvm in advanced

Answer (score 1):

SOA is an architectural style that helps build services or components that are loosely coupled but talk to each other through well-defined interfaces such as WSDL or RAML. The services can be run on application servers and can be integrated through an Enterprise Service Bus (ESB). Both ESB and application servers are categorized as middleware.